# django replace html href and src to a {% static %} tag

Tags: html, regex, django, django-templates, pycharm

how I can django replace html href and src to a static tag in Pycharm?
For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<a href="/"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
```

into

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'landing/libs/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">
<a href="/"><img src="{% static "landing/img/logo.png" %}" alt=""></a>
```

thx!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find and replace into the project with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Into the file selection, you can specify that you want to perform replacements in `*.html` files, and that we want to search for a *regex* (check the checkbox *Regular expression*).

As pattern, you can write a pattern like:

```
\b(src|href)="([^"]*)"\b
```

and as patttern to replace:

```
$1="{% static '$2' %}"
```

You might want to consider tweaking the pattern a bit, for example to only replace paths that start with `libs/`, etc.

this will then propose the changes. I advise you to look through these manually since there can be *false positives*: proposed changes, that should not change.

Comment: This pattern doesn't work for me in Pycharm 2020.1

Can you suggest an adjustment Willem? Would be a big help

Comment: Can you suggest a LINUX sed command for this?

Answer (score 1):

Above answer didn't help me, so I created my own.

find: `<(link|img|script)[^>]*(?:href|src)=["']([^"']*)["']`

replace: `<$1 src="{% static '$2' %}"`